# Möbius strip and a neighborhood of the projective line

Tags: general-topology

Möbius strip is homomorphic to a neighborhood of a projective line in $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$. It seems obvious but I don't know how to prove it. Help me, please:(

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're referring to my previous answer. I hope this helps. Suppose you have $S^2$ under the relation $x \sim -x$. If we identify every point on the North Hemisphere with the South Hemisphere, I'm left with the North Hemisphere as is plus some identification I need to do on the equator (essentially a bowl whose boundary I need to do some work on). Now let's just look at an epsilon (closed) neighbourhood of this equator, pre-identification. It's basically just an annulus. For visualization's sake, I'm going to to think of my annulus as a small cylinder with a vertical axis.

So now my task is to show that $S^1 \times [0,1]$ modulo antipodal identifications on the "bottom" $S^1$ (i.e. $S^1 \times \{0\})$ gives me a Möbius strip. I tried to write it in words but a picture worked way better so I have attached a picture below and a description underneath. Here I have represented the cylinder by cutting it vertically and unrolling it into a rectangle. I add blue arrows on the side to indicate that it needs to be reglued.

[image]

In the first picture, we have the cylinder. In order to do the antipodal identification, I cut the rectangle in half. The antipodal identification basically identifies the first purple edge with the second. In doing so, I have to reglue the cut later so I add the red edges. Shifting B to the left so that the purple lines coincide, and reflecting it over, we obtain the final figure which is the standard polygon for the Möbius strip.

P.S. sorry for the scrappy image. I drew it on my phone real quick.