# How to write a diffeomorphism between an open set of the real projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{R})$ and the Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, projective-space

I am trying to solve the following exercise, from do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry:

> Show that the real projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{R})$ is not orientable.
>   *Hint*: Show that if the manifold $M$ is orientable, then every open set of $M$ is an orientable manifold. Observe that $P^2(\Bbb{R})$ contains an open set diffeomorphic to the Möbius strip, which is not orientable.

I am trying to follow the hint, and managed to prove the first part. Now, I have the intuition that if we take a neighborhood of the equator in the sphere $S^2$, this amounts to an open set in $P^2(\Bbb{R})$. On the other hand, it also amounts to the Möbius band, which I think of, following the book, as the quotient manifold $C/G$, where $C$ is a right cylinder and $G = \{ Id, A\}$, where $A$ is the antipodal map.

In other words, I am thinking of a map
$$
U \subset P^2(\Bbb{R}) \rightarrow V \subset S^2 \rightarrow C \xrightarrow{\pi} C/G \\
[p]  \mapsto p \mapsto q \mapsto[q]
$$
where $V = \{p \in S^2 \ : \ |p_3| < \varepsilon\}$ is a neighborhood of the equator and $q$ can be obtained from $p$ by
$$
p = (p_1, p_2, p_3) \mapsto \left(\frac{p_1}{\sqrt{p_1^2 + p_2^2}}, \frac{p_2}{\sqrt{p_1^2 + p_2^2}}, p_3 \right) = q
$$
However, I am not able to write this map explicitly, nor show that it is a differomorphism. I am also havin difficulty determining the domain $U \subset P^2(\Bbb{R})$.

I will apreciate any hints or solutions.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: If you're okay with cutting and pasting for surfaces, then you can look at my answer here that shows how it works https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616318/m%c3%b6bius-strip-and-a-neighborhood-of-the-projective-line/3616454#3616454 the diagram should help you also write down a specific map

Comment: The beginning of your sequence of maps makes no sense. But the cylindrical neighborhood $C$ of the equator maps down to a neighborhood of "the $\Bbb RP^1$ at infinity" in $\Bbb RP^2$. This is the open subset diffeomorphic to the Möbius strip.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Thanks a lot. I understood the diagram and now I am working on defining the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do Carmo introduces the (open) Möbius band as the quotient manifold $C/G$, where $C = S^1 \times (-1,1)$ is an open circular cylinder and $G=\{Id,A\}$, where $A$ is the antipodal map.

$P^2(\mathbb R)$ is quotient manifold $S^2/G$. Let $N =(0,0,1)$ and $S = (0,0,-1)$ denote the north and south pole of $S^2$ and $M = S^2 \setminus \{N,S\}$. Then $M/G = P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\}$, where $P$ is the equivalence class consisting of the pair of antipodal points $\{N,S\}$. Clearly $P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\}$ is an open subset of $P^2(\mathbb R)$.

Obviously the map
$$\phi : M \to S^1 \times (-1,1), \phi(x,y,z) = (x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2},y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z)$$
(which is a special case of the map you considered in your question) is a diffeomorphism which is compatible with the action of $G$. It therefore induces a diffeomorphism

$$\phi' : P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\} \to C/G .$$
This is what you have been looking for.

PS. The inverse of $\phi$ is
$$\psi : S^1 \times (-1,1) \to M, \psi(u,v,w) = (\sqrt{1-w^2}u,\sqrt{1-w^2}v,w) .$$

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you very much for your answer. In order to construct $\phi'$, we are composing with the inverse of the projection $\Pi: M \to P^2(\Bbb{R}$ and $\phi: C \to C/G$, aren't we? But these are not global diffeomorphisms. So don't we need to restrict our domains?

Comment: The quotient map $\Pi : S^2 \to P^2(\mathbb R)$ restricts to map $\Pi'  : M \to P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\}$ which is again a quotient map. In fact we have $M/G = P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\}$. The map $\phi : M \to C = S^1 \times (-1,1)$ is a diffeomorphism which is compatible with the action of $G$. It therefore induces a diffeomorphism $\phi' : P^2(\mathbb R) \setminus \{P\} \to C/G$ which has the property $\phi' \circ \Pi' = q \circ \phi$, where $q : C \to C/G$ is the quotient map.