# Diffeomorphims compatible with an action.

Tags: projective-space, diffeomorphism

Hello I'm reading the following thread

[How to write a diffeomorphism between an open set of the real projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{R})$ and the Möbius strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670244/how-to-write-a-diffeomorphism-between-an-open-set-of-the-real-projective-plane)

But in the same I find the following afirmation

> is a diffeomorphism which is compatible with the action of G. It therefore induces a diffeomorphism

But I don't know where find this proposition or how to prove the same. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: In the linked question, the two-element group acts on the two-sphere and on the cylinder $S^1\times(-1,1)$. _Compatible with the action_ means _equivariant_ with respect to these actions. Here, in less fancy terms, orbits on the sphere map to orbits on the cylinder, so there is an induced mapping from the quotient of the sphere to the quotient of the cylinder.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang, But where Can I to find the demostration and theory about this point?